# python closes after input?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm brand new to python! My programs keep closing immediately after I input some data. So for example, I run this:

```
def main():
  kilometers = eval(input("How many kilometers do you want to convert to miles?"))
  miles = kilometers * 0.62
  print(kilometers, "kilometers is", miles, "miles!")
main()
```

And after I put in a number, the program shuts down without displaying an answer. It works just fine on my school's computers. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why use `eval` when you're not expecting an expression? Have you the put the same input on your computer as you have on the school computer?

Comment: like i said, I'm brand new at this. I literally just picked up a book on it two days ago. This is the same code i put into python at my school and it works, but on my laptop, the program just closes immediately

Answer (score 1):

You've probably used Python 3 on your school's computers. On Python 2 [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) already does [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) on the input that user entered where as on Python 3 [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) just returns a string that needs to be converted to number in one way or another.

If you want to convert the example to work on Python 2 I'd suggest that you use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) that returns the user input as a string and convert it to number with [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float). You also need to either use `print` statement or import `print` function from `__future__` as I've done in the following example:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def main():
    kilometers = float(raw_input("How many kilometers do you want to convert to miles?"))
    miles = kilometers * 0.62

    print(kilometers, "kilometers is", miles, "miles!")

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program exits immediately after input. You can block it simply with a "raw_input()" at the end. If you're using Python 2.7 (as opposed to 3.x) you should use raw_input() instead of input(). Using eval is a bit strange here, so let's use a float. Finally as this is tagged Python 2.7, I made the print use a formatted string because it feels more 2.7-like:

```
def main():
  kilometers = float(raw_input("How many kilometers do you want to convert to miles? "))
  miles = kilometers * 0.62
  print "%f kilometers is %f miles!" % (kilometers, miles)
main()
raw_input()
```

Now your program will exit after you hit Enter!